# jQuery selector question

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have encountered code that leverages jQuery, similar to the following.

```
NAMESPACE = {
    propertyA : $("#selector-a"),
    propertyB : $("#selector-b")
}

$(NAMESPACE.propertyA).click(function(){
    // ...
});
```

This seems to work, even though the syntax for attaching the click handler should be.

```
NAMESPACE.propertyA.click(function(){
    // ...
});
```

Does jQuery have the built in ability to resolve the following, despite the incorrect syntax?

```
$($("#my-selector")).click ... etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will handle this if necessary. You really ought not use this syntax though if it's within your control. I tested against the following and got the same results with both:

```
$($("li")).click(function(e){
  alert(e.target);
});

//--

$("li").click(function(e){
  alert(e.target);
});
```

Comment: Use of this syntax was not my decision, and I understand that it is not desirable.

Comment: @jerome: No blood, no foul :) I understand having to work with other people's finicky code.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. jQuery allows as arguments to the `$`:

- A CSS selector
- A DOM element
- An array of DOM elements
- A jQuery object
- A function (which will be called as part of `$.ready()`)

All of these are valid syntax as far as jQuery is concerned, though performance may suffer in some of these cases.

Since your `NAMESPACE.properties` are jQuery elements, this will work.